# The difference of local variables in main and other function

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, gdb, ubuntu-14.04

I'm confused. I declare a variable in `main` function, and another variable in another function. But in the gdb, I find that the program visits the variable in `main` function by `%esp` register, and visits the variable in another function by `%ebp` register. shouldn't it all be visited by `%ebp` function? Or it's a hidden rule that visit by `%esp` register in `main` that I don't know?

```
/* source_file.c */
#include <stdio.h>

void localfunc(void)
{
    int local_in_func;
    local_in_func = 0x21;
    printf("local_in_func = %d\n", local_in_func);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int local_in_main;
    local_in_main = 0x97;
    printf("local_in_main = %d\n", local_in_main);
    return 0;
}
```

And its disassemble code below:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x08048407 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x08048408 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x0804840a <+3>: and    $0xfffffff0,%esp    ; visit local_in_main by esp
   0x0804840d <+6>: sub    $0x20,%esp
   0x08048410 <+9>: movl   $0x97,0x1c(%esp)
   0x08048418 <+17>:    mov    $0x8048524,%eax
   0x0804841d <+22>:    mov    0x1c(%esp),%edx
   0x08048421 <+26>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x08048425 <+30>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048428 <+33>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x0804842d <+38>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x08048432 <+43>:    leave  
   0x08048433 <+44>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disassemble localfunc
Dump of assembler code for function localfunc:
   0x080483e4 <+0>: push   %ebp
   0x080483e5 <+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x080483e7 <+3>: sub    $0x28,%esp
   0x080483ea <+6>: movl   $0x21,-0xc(%ebp)    ; visit local_in_func by ebp
   0x080483f1 <+13>:    mov    $0x8048510,%eax
   0x080483f6 <+18>:    mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
   0x080483f9 <+21>:    mov    %edx,0x4(%esp)
   0x080483fd <+25>:    mov    %eax,(%esp)
   0x08048400 <+28>:    call   0x8048300 <printf@plt>
   0x08048405 <+33>:    leave  
   0x08048406 <+34>:    ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

My tools are:

- OS: ubuntu 12.04
- compile: gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
- debug: GNU gdb (Ubuntu/Linaro 7.4-2012.04-0ubuntu2.1) 7.4-2012.04

Comment: code for `main()` also has an additional `and    $0xfffffff0,%esp`, why is that?

Comment: Try with `-O`. Your functions are not equivalent as one returns something. The assumptions gcc can make about stack alignment might not be the same for main.

Comment: and $0xfffffff0,%esp aligns stack.

Comment: I try with `-O`, and change the `main` into `void main(void)`, this is equal to the other function. And the result I get is that in the both function, the program visits the local variable by `%esp` register.

Answer (score 5):

Conventionally, `%esp` is the stack pointer and `%ebp` is the 'base' pointer which is usually set to where the stack pointer was at the start of the function.

Functions make local variables by pushing them onto the stack either with a direct `push` or by the logical equivalent of subtracting an offset from `%esp` and accessing the space between the old `%esp` (i.e. `%ebp`) and the new `%esp`.

This can either be done with a positive offset from `%esp` (such as via `0x1c(%esp)` in `main`) or via a negative offset from `%ebp` (such as `-0xc(%ebp)` in `local_function1). There is no logical difference although compilers have many performance heuristics for choosing between multiple ways to achieve the same thing.

As your code is not optimised I would not put much weight into the choice, it may be the result of a heuristic that has some impact in other situations but I wouldn't expect it to make much difference here.

Comment: And on x86 some functions don't even need to move sp, due to "red zone" (point being: compiler does not need to obey textbook "rules").

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I understand mostly of your answer, but I know nothing about "red zone", I will search it later. And my problem is that I change `%esp` in main function by embedded `asm` code, and it will result that I lost my local variables in `main` function. So how can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: There are different ways to do this. One is to use extended inline assembly syntax, that allows you to use variables in assembly... See here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say it clearly. I mean that I declare a local variable in `main` function by `C` code, and then I change `%esp` register by inline `asm` code, and then I try to use `C` code to visit the local variable I declared, but the program visits the local variable by `%esp` register, so before I change, such as the variable locates at `-0xc(%esp)`, but now `0xc(%esp)` isn't the variable's location because I changed the `%esp`. I'm not a native English speaker, maybe my description isn't clear, sorry about that. Thanks for your reply sincerely.